# state is not iterable in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

Why my state is not iterable here

Reducer component:

```
export default function reducer(state = [], action) {
   
    switch(action.type){
        case actions.ADD_CAR:
            return[
                ...state, 
                 {
                    carId: ++carID, 
                    model: action.payload.model, 
                    color: action.payload.color,
                    regNo: action.payload.regNo,
                    owner: action.payload.owner,
                    reconditioned: action.payload.reconditioned 
                }
            ];
        case actions.DELETE_CAR:
            return state.filter((car) => car.carId !== action.payload.id);
        default:
            return state;
    }

}
```

Comment: I've created a sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-redux-forked-19lpb1 but can't replicate your issue. Is there anything else that could be modifying the state?

Comment: no, its just adding a state, no modifying

Comment: Are you using combine reducers feature in your project? Code provided is not enough for reproduction, try to add more info to it.